# How to style multiple Feature types in Leaflet from a single GeoJSON FeatureCollection

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have Point, MultiPolygon, and Linestring features in a single FeatureCollection. I want to style Points with circleMarker(), and the others normally. I add Points to an idToFeature object for manipulation with JavaScript, but can't add the non-point features.

Using Leaflet 1.3.3, if I use pointToLayer:, Points are styled fine, and the other types do render, with a default blue (don't know why, as they aren't points). I have tried using onEachFeature: instead, and can style non-points that way, but can't figure how to generate circleMarkers for points.

**What I have**
(can't style MultiPolygons, or add them to my idToFeature object for JS manipulation)

```
// geom is an array of features inc. Point, MultiPolygon, Linestring
renderPlaces = function(geoms) {
  data = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":geoms}
  idToFeature = {}
  mappy.createPane('placePane');
  mappy.getPane('placePane').style.zIndex = 200;
  features = L.geoJSON(data, {
    pane: 'placePane',
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      identifier = feature.properties.id;
      if(feature.type=='Point'){
        marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, styles.place_default)
          .bindPopup(feature.properties.title+' (id:'+identifier+')');
        // add to array for programmatic selection
        idToFeature[identifier] = marker
        return marker
      }
    }
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

**What I tried** (one take anyway)

```
features = L.geoJSON(data, {
  style: function (feature) {
    if(feature.type=="Point"){
      return {color: "#009900"};
    } else {
      return {color: "#000099"};
    }
  }
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if(feature.type == 'Point'){
      console.log('point', feature)
      marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, styles.place_default)
      return marker
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

I'd prefer not to break the GeoJSON into separate type-specific FeatureCollections, feel certain I shouldn't have to...but how?

Comment: If you inspect `feature` in the `onEachFeature` function, can you identify whether the 'type` contains what you expect it to?

Comment: You can see in the last section that I do inspect the `feature` for type, and render circleMarker if it's a Point. The question was how to render the features with other types. `onEachFeature` docs say it is called "once for each created Feature, after it has been created and styled." So how do I create and style the MultiPolygon and Linestring features at that point? I will keep trying things, but thought someone might know a ready approach.

Answer (score 0):

I cobbled a solution. It doesn't seem ideal, but works: use both `pointToLayer` and `onEachFeature`, one after the other.

```
    features = L.geoJSON(data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        count_features +=1;
        identifier = feature.properties.whgid;
        if(feature.type=='Point'){
          marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, styles.marker_default
          ).bindPopup(feature.properties.title+' (whg id:'+identifier+')');
          // add to array for selection
          idToFeature[identifier] = marker
          return marker
        }
      },
      onEachFeature: function(feature,layer) {
        identifier = feature.properties.whgid;
        if(feature.type != 'Point'){
          layer.setStyle(styles.default)
          idToFeature[identifier] = layer
        }
      }
    }).addTo(map);
```